# How could I create a component in this way?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I'd like to create a component, tabpanel, treepanel, or gridpanel, which is inherited from my base object, this base object extends from Ext.container.Container, and then pass config parameters to it. How could I make this happen?

I've tried as below, it won't work.

```
Ext.define('MyProj.base.Component', {
extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
requires:[
    'Ext.tab.*',
    'Ext.tree.*',
    'Ext.grid.*',
    'Ext.form.*',
    'Ext.data.Store'
],

//Position, Size, CSS decoration
layout: 'accordion',
//region: '',
width: null,
height: null,
//html: '&#160;',
//bodyPadding: null,

//Operation
collapsible: true,
closable: false,
draggable: false,
floatable: true,
autoScroll: true,

//Data
store: null,
//items: null,

initComponent : function(){
    var me = this;

    me.callParent(arguments);
},

constructor: function(cfg, defaultType){
    var me = this;
    me.xtype = 'tabpanel';
    me.defaultType = defaultType;
    me.baseCls = Ext.baseCSSPrefix+defaultType;
    me.componentCls = Ext.baseCSSPrefix+defaultType;
    Ext.apply(me, cfg || {});

    me.callParent();
}


});
```

Comment: Of course it cannot work the way you tried, but the problem with your question is that you did not explain what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way you can create a component.

First of all, tab panel, grid and tree panel all inherit from `Ext.container.Container`. Thus you must not extend that class, but one of the child classes.

Then, you must not use `constructor` as you do.

Unfortunately you are not clear at all about what you want to achieve. I imagine you would like to create a tab panel with two tabs, one with a grid, and the other with a tree, or something similar.

You could achieve this with code like follows :

```
Ext.define('MyProj.base.Component', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
// layout: 'accordion' 
// a tab panel cannot have an accordion layout 
    items: [{
        xtype: 'grid', 
        ... 
    }, {
        xtype: 'treepanel', 
        ... 
    }], 
    collapsible: true,
    closable: false,
    draggable: false,
    floatable: true,
    autoScroll: true,
```

})

I hope this helps you to come closer to use the framework the way it is intended.

If I didn't get what you want to do, so please try to reformulate your question such that it is more clear.

**Edit**

According to your explanation (you gave as an answer and that is deleted meanwhile), you try to create a function that can return any of your components. There is no reason you implement this.

If you have your special `MyProj.base.TabPanel` and you want ot instatiate, you have to use `Ext.widget`. You will add an `alias` to your component, like

```
Ext.define('MyProj.base.TabPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.myproj-tab'
```

You can then reference this component anywhere with `xtype: 'myproj-tab'`, and create an instance with `Ext.widget('myproj-tab')`. This function will just do what you wanted to achieve. There is no need to reinvent the wheel. It is already build-in.

Comment: Thank you very much Lorenz Meyer! Your answer is just what I've done, and I was thinking it should have another way to do this. say, there's a method called createNewObject in my App.js, I'm trying to create a component dynamically.

Comment: @TaoWang I edited my question. I hope this is the answer you expected... You wrote about a more 'elegant' and 'efficient' solution. Elegance is subjective and efficience can be measured, but most of the time using a framework as it is meant to be used is more efficient and more elegant than trying to invent one's own approach that is going against the spirit of the framework.

Comment: Thanks, Lorenz Meyer! Elegnace means simple, I'm trying to do is to make js files as few as possible. My idea is to parse json-like layout template and render it at client side so that I can free from layout design and layout replacement. I've create a recursion to parse json-like file, it worked well except for GridPanel, TreePanel part. I just want to use ExtJS in an Object-Oriented way, and it should be used like that. Javascript is sort of OO language, it DOES have prototypal inheritance.